# Implement custom incoming call screen in android

Tags: android

In my application, i want to implement the incoming call screen( which is fake).So user can get the fake call at scheduled time.Is there any way to implement the custom in call screen( which exactly looks like the real incoming call is made).
Please suggest any solution for this,I stuck with this problem from last week.

Answer (score 0):

Call screens can be different on various devices, depending on manufacturer (i.e. HTC) or Android version, so you'd have to mimic them all if you want to make generic app.

Comment: How can I make custom in call screen for my application. please suggest me any code or way to implement it in my application & I test the application on Samsung galaxy ace.

Comment: as any other layout. Or do a screengrab of system screen and use ImageView in your laout to just display it. If you want to add some overlays like texts etc, use RelativeLayout

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made the custom screen with relative layout. But I can't make the custom slider which looks like a default slider of device for answering or rejecting call.So,please suggest me for making the slider which looks like default slider.